# Failsafe VPN solution?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, pptp

I need to set up a VPN.

I experimented with PPTP, but I got a lot of problems. VPN connection doesn't work behind some routers or mobile / wifi connections.

So I'm looking for a failsafe VPN solution. Something that should always work, no matter where we are. Just like SSH or HTTP.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You tagged your question with openvpn.  Have you tried it? it is about the easiest vpn solution to get up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I've used ppp over [ssh](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/ppp-ssh/) and [SSL](http://bremford.org/tips/QuickStunnelVPN.html) - which has worked for me - even with VOIP - but doesn't work with MSWindows or mobile devices.

Have you tried [openVPN](http://openmaniak.com/openvpn.php) (essentially ppp over SSL - but there's clients for MSWindows, iOS and Android as well as Linux and other Unixen).

(you might not need support for multiple devices - but designing it in from the begining avoids having to reimplement if you ever do need it)

Comment: +1 on the openvpn. Put it on port 443, and it should go through pretty much any firewall.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN should work no matter where you are, I used it briefly on my Android phone.  It worked behind several wifi connections, and on mobile.  The only issue I had with the app I used ( I couldn't find anything excellent, but others may have found something better ) was that it drops the VPN when you switch wifi's or you switch from wifi to mobile network.

That said, PPTP is no longer considered secure, so OpenVPN is a better choice to begin with on that front.